# Windows Server 2012 R2 running a *.cmd file from a UNC path issue

Tags: c#, cmd

I have machine A and machine B. I am trying to run an executable (Install.exe) file from machine A, to perform some action on machine B without logging on to B and without the need to copy the exe on to machine B. I am using below powershell script to do that:-

```
$securePassword= ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -force

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("Domain\username",$securePassword)

 Invoke-Command -Authentication credssp -Credential $cred -ComputerName "MachineB" `
-ScriptBlock { & '\\MachineA\myFolder\Install.exe'}
```

The exe runs without any issue and generates a text file on MachineB. But that exe in-turn calls a deploy.cmd file, this is where I do not see any action specified in the deploy.cmd file happens on machine B. Following is the code in the Install.exe (Written in C#) that calls the deploy.cmd file. As can be seen I am specifying the UNC path on Machine A where both the Install.exe and deploy.cmd files reside.

```
 StringBuilder myStr = new StringBuilder("deploy.cmd ");
 ProcessStartInfo psf = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + myStr.ToString());
 psf.WorkingDirectory = @"\\MachineA\myFolder";
 Process p = Process.Start(psf);
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Any Idea what’s the issue is?

Comment: You should run `cmd.exe /k \\MachineA\myFolder\deploy.cmd`

Comment: I tried your suggestion by Specifying the UNC path for "deploy.cmd" as below:- StringBuilder myStr = new StringBuilder(@"\\MachineA\myFolder\deploy.cmd "); But no luck

Comment: While i think you should use `/c` (run command and close at end) and not `/k` (run command and keep open), maybe the problem is not the call to the batch file but the batch file itself. Batch files executed from UNC paths can fail in references to the paths if not correctly handled. Can you include the batch file in the question?

Comment: You figure this out?  I can't execute on the share with Filezilla, but could before with the same code on the actual computer.